# Datafield on textbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I made a UpdateCommand for my dataadapter in my MySQL connection.

```
myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE tblTable SET anotherTableID = ?antaID, tableText = ?tabText WHERE tabID = 1", myConnection)

myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("?antaID", MySqlDbType.Int32, 15, "antaID")
myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("?tabText", MySqlDbType.String, 15, "tabText")
```

Is there a way to link these up parameters to variables or textfields? Cause I want the value from a textbox to be the value of `tabText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("?tabText", MySqlDbType.String, 15, txtTabText.Text)
```

Assuming your Textbox control Id is txtTabText

Comment: Somehow it adds NULL to databasefield, even though there is a value in the textbox.

Comment: @then you are overwriting /re initializing that somewhere in your code. User visual studio breakpoints to see when it becomes null. Are you loading the data to this control on a page load ? I guess you may need to check a !IsPostBack